# How to transpose data in Excel based on dates

Tags: excel, transpose

I have data in csv file which I want to transpose

The initial data looks something like:

[image]

I want to transpose the data like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this in excel? I tried the regular transpose in excel but the date would convert to columns instead of rows. Can this be done in any other tool?

Comment: what Excel version do you have?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I'm using Office 365

Comment: Then Power Query is the goto in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Open Excel with a new workbook

2) Click "Data" / "From text csv"

[image]

3) Select the csv file

4) Set the parameters to import it (depends on your locale)

[image]

5) Click "edit"

[image]

6) Select the columns that hold the prices

[image]

7) Click "Transform" | Unpivot columns

[image]

8) In the formula bar (if it's not active, click the check on the view tab), change "Attribute" to "Cat" and "Value" to "Price"

[image]

[image]

9) Click "Home" | "Close and load to"

[image]

10) Select "Table" and the location

[image]

Let me know if it works.